# Array and module

Tags: c++, arrays, module

Hello i am working on a program to store a users input of prices into an array. then have a module accept the price array and return tax.  here is what i have so far. my module keeps producing LNK2019.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    double PrArray[20] = {}, total_price, tax_rate, price, tax;
    int i;
    double TAXOWED();
void main()
   {
    cout << "input the sales tax rate as a decimal ";
    cin >> tax_rate;
    cout << "\nplease enter a price or 0 to quit ";
    i = 0;
    cin >> price;
    PrArray[i] = price;
    while (price > 0 && i < 19)
{
    i++;
    cout << "please enter a price or 0 to quit ";
    cin >> price;
    PrArray[i] = price;
}
for (i = 0; i < 19; i++)
{
    cout << "\n";
    cout << PrArray[i];
}

TAXOWED();

system("PAUSE");
return;

}
double TAXOWED(double PrArray[], int i)
{
    double total_tax;
    for (i = 0; i < 19; i++)
{
    tax = tax_rate * PrArray[i];
    total_tax = tax;
}
    return(total_tax);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function declaration and definition don't match

```
// Declaration
double TAXOWED();

// Definition
double TAXOWED(double PrArray[], int i);
```

So essentially your are declaring a function and never defining it, then defining a separate function below.

Comment: So how would i get the Tax owed function to return tax for each element in my PrArray?

Comment: @Josh.O , you can pass PrArray to TAXOWED function. Now this function evaluates tax for each price in PrArray and returns last evaluated tax.

Answer (score 0):

Relaying on your comment, the code should looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double TAXOWED(double price, double tax_rate)
{
    return tax_rate * price;
}

int main()
{
    double PrArray[20], total_tax[20], tax_rate, price;

    cout << "input the sales tax rate as a decimal ";
    cin >> tax_rate;
    cout << "\nplease enter a price or 0 to quit ";
    cin >> price;
    if ( price == 0 )
        return -1;
    int i = 0;
    PrArray[i] = price;
    for (i = 1; i < 20; i++)
    {
        cout << "please enter a price or 0 to quit " ;
        cin >> price;
        PrArray[i] = price;
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 20; i++)
        total_tax[i] = TAXOWED(PrArray[i], tax_rate);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        cout << "Tax for price #" << i << " : " << total_tax[i] << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0; 
}
```

This code will allow you to set `tax_rate`, each `price` value and output `tax_rate` for each price.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what i have now. i need the chart at the end to have all the total prices added together

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// declerations
double PrArray[20], total_tax[20], tax_rate, price, total_price;
int i;
double TAXOWED(double price, double tax_rate)
{
return tax_rate * price;
}
void main()
{
cout << "input the sales tax rate as a decimal ";
cin >> tax_rate;
cout << "\nplease enter a price or 0 to quit ";
i = 0;
cin >> price;
PrArray[i] = price;
while (price > 0 && i < 19)
{
    i++;
    cout << "please enter a price or 0 to quit ";
    cin >> price;
    PrArray[i] = price;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    total_tax[i] = TAXOWED(PrArray[i], tax_rate);
}

system("CLS");


cout << "                                   Prices";

cout << "\ntaxrate % " << tax_rate;

cout << "\nprices              tax             Total price ";
cout << "\n__________________________________________________";

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    cout << "\n" << PrArray[i] << "                   " << total_tax[i] << "                   " << PrArray[i] + total_tax[i];
}
for (int)
system("PAUSE");
return;
```

}